# How do you do HTML tables?

Tags: .html, table

I wonder how you guys do tables in ExpressionEngine? Sometimes there's a clear need for tables - semantically.

Matrix is not an option since it can only have a predefined amount of columns.

I used markdown tables, but most of the time I don't need a header. The only usable thing I found was textile tables, but I want to get rid of textile and use markdown wherever I can.

Any ideas? 
cheers
stefan

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 16):

[**Content Elements**](http://www.krea.com/content-elements) contains an option for tables that lets the user create columns on the fly. Haven't tried it yet but it looks pretty awesome and seems to have [useful template tags](http://www.krea.com/docs/content-elements/table/) for the table element.

[image]

Comment: I have and it's very good.

Comment: yeah! content elements is the only thing that is exactly what I want! I might ask them to release this as a separate add-on?! content elements is a great concept, but I am afraid of using such a big add-on. I prefer smaller add-ons in case the developer stops developing the add-on. there's also grid lite, but it does not seem to be in active production.

Comment: Krea is a well know addon developer. I wouldn't worry about them going vaporware on you. Also size of addon has no impact on whether an addon stops getting developed. Take Lumis Image Sizer. One day it mysteriously disappeared, eventually to have its features replicated by other developers. A small addon that disappears, if its crucial to your site, will be as bad as a big addon disappearing. I'd recommend giving this addon a shot if it does what you need it to do. also don't forget to click the check next to the answer that best answers your question.

Comment: you are absolutely right! and the add-on is rock solid (I have purchased it to test it). but my preference is to rely mostly on first-party add-ons. replacing a image sizer add-on is less painful than to change a whole content strategy, not?

Comment: I also work with CE and I can confirm, that the tables work well. Style and content are completely seperated and you can use if-statements to apply CSS-classes to tables. Tah Taht will give Editors the freedom to use different sorts of tables on different parts of the site.

Answer (score 15):

Email support[at]objectivehtml.com. I have a new add-on that I have been developing since Spring 2012 that does exactly this. Like everything I build, its focus is on a rock solid and configurable API. It's still not ready for a public release, but it's used on a number of our clients' sites (in production). I am happy to let you install it and give it a shot to see if fits your needs.

Comment: wow... email sent! this is a long awaited moment! OMG - stack exchange is just amazing!

Answer (score 4):

The Redactor.js has a nice table builder if you want a WYSIWYG field type.

You can demo it here: http://imperavi.com/redactor/

All of the Redactor field types should come with this feature:

- [Editor](http://www.devdemon.com/editor/)
- [Redactee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/redactee)
- [Reedactor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reedactor)

[image: Redactor.js Table Builder]

Comment: Also note I think the first two add-ons I listed (not sure about the third) will allow you to create "profiles" where in the case of tables you could have a profile which had only source ie. the </> button and the table button itself and maybe a few other basic buttons like bold, italic, link etc. This in turn would allow you to have a field which was for building tables and nothing more~.

Comment: I am not a fan of the wysiwyg approach, but as you mentioned, it could be ok if I would configure it to only produce tables... nice idea! I'll give it a try! thanks!

Comment: Don't mention it :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about using tables as a fieldtype? There's no table fieldtype in EE, but you can use [Wygwam](http://pixelandtonic.com/wygwam) and configure it to show the options for building a free-form table in the editor.

Comment: There is no FT yet*. ;)

Comment: lol saw your answer after I posted, I'm intrigued :)

Comment: He says "no FT yet" though, it's been that way for a year now ;)

Comment: Well actually there is: Content Elements like Alex mentioned.

Comment: yeah - only content elements is available. but it's a bit too bloated to use it just for tables...

Comment: Content Elements was not on my radar at all! It's a module I will check out in the future

Comment: I've found Wygwam the only reasonable solution for non techie users. If the table already exists in Word or Excel copy/paste works most of the time, and if you know HTML you can always go in and modify/clean up the code in source view.