# Tables for product data

Tags: html, table

I am wanting to have a predefined tablelike fieldtype for ecommerce products. I am talking about data that needs to be entered for every product like SKU, EAN, lenght, weight, height, color and so on.

I have looked at this [thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/how-do-you-do-html-tables) and I am using Content Elements but I am missing the possibility to predefine the tables first row.

Anybody having an idea about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case [matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) or the [native grid field](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html) might be better suited to what you're trying to accomplish.

The thread you referenced is aimed at having a variable set of columns and rows. However, in this case you have predefined columns (SKU, EAN, ect.) and only a variable amount of rows.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I guess you are right. I guess in my thinkings about this I never considered Matrix because I had a vertical table in mind and Matrix or Grid is being entered (or presented) horizontally. Of course this is only in the CP and doesn't affect the frontend presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to add separate custom fields for product data type. eg

Field - SKU
Field - Height
Field - Width
Field - Length

You could then use this data several ways:

1. On a product detail page, simply list of the values
2. In a data table for multiple products, eg

   SKU Height Width Length
   {exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
   {cf_sku} {cf_height} {cf_width} {cf_length}
   {/exp:channel:entries}

(sorry SE doesnt allow table tags but you get the idea)