# Create a perfect table using Matrix?

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to create a perfect table so i can add as many cells and rows as i want?

Any help will be much appreciated, expression engine version 2.7.3 and latest matrix.

Thanks,

Wes.

Comment: What kind of content will go in your table? If you don't need the specialized cell types that Matrix has or aren't tied to Matrix is some other way, take a look at Krea Content Elements. It let's you define columns on the fly. More in this answer http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1446/22

Answer (score 2):

No - you can create as many rows as you want, but not as many columns as you want. Columns must be defined beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

As Derek has mention with Matrix you can not create as many columns as you want on the fly when you are publishing/editing an entry with Matrix.

You might take a look at something like [Content Elements](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements) which allows the user to create predefined elements on the fly including creating tables.

Also most of the WYSIWYG editors available today have the ability for you to build tables on the fly by hitting a table button and defining the fields their.